# How to execute the Update statement in the Stored Procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  Stored Procedure in MYSQL 5.7.33
where I have a select statement in that one, I'm printing update statement and trying to execute that statement to update the values in the table.

My Sample Procedure looks like Below :

```
  DELIMITER &&  
    ALTER PROCEDURE update_stmt ()  
    BEGIN  
        
   SELECT concat(update Test.sample SET COL = 0 where ID = \'',ID,'\','; ) as stmt FROM 
      Test.Sample into @s; 
       SET @sql = @s
       PREPARE stmt from @sql;
       EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
       
    END &&  
    DELIMITER ;  

  Error  : I'm getting  more than a row.
```

In the Select  Statement I will get  multiple  update statements like this

```
Update Test.sample SET COL = 0 WHERE ID = 1 ;
Update Test.sample SET COL = 0 WHERE ID = 2 ;
Update Test.sample SET COL = 0 WHERE ID = 3 ;
...
...
...
Update Test.sample SET COL = 0 WHERE ID = n;
```

How to execute multiple update statements in Procedure.

Note : This one is small part of the entire procedure which I'm looking for suggestion, based on that I need to add more logic.
Thanks

Comment: Before going any further there is no ALTER PROCEDURE in mysql is the tagging correct?

Comment: @P.Salmon, there is ALTER PROCEDURE in MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-procedure.html

Comment: @mohan111 Why not tell what is the problem you are trying to solve. It is generally considered bad to serialize the SQL statemrnts which you can achieve in one set operation.

Comment: @slaakso Yes, ALTER PROCEDURE exists. But it does not allow to alter the procedure's code/parameters, this statement can be used to change the characteristics of the stored procedure only. When you need to edit SP code you must drop and recreate it.

Comment: @slaakso I want to execute the update statements which comes from the select statement with in the Procedure

Comment: @mohan111 (1) You must drop existing SP and create new one. (2) You'd concat the criteria only (using GROUP_CONCAT) and obtain one statement like `Update Test.sample SET COL = 0 WHERE ID IN (1,2,3, ... ) ;`.

Comment: @P.Salmon, the question is bit unclear. You are right that ALTER PROCEDURE cannnot be used as stated in the question. The code itself looked like a MySQL code.

Comment: @mohan111 instead of doing what you are now trying, why not tell what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve. The current method is not the recommended one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code should be (I assume that `Test.sample.id` is numeric)

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_stmt;

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE update_stmt ()  
BEGIN  
SELECT concat('update Test.sample SET COL = 0 where id IN (',
              GROUP_CONCAT(id),
              ');')
FROM Test.Sample 
INTO @sql; 
PREPARE stmt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

From the other side your code updates all rows with non-null value in `id`, so your code performs the same like simple

```sql
UPDATE Test.sample 
SET COL = 0 
WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: thanks  for the answer I have implemented this  in my code

Comment: when I have no data to update it is  showing  error right syntax  to use near NULL at line

Comment: @mohan111 Wrap PREPARE/EXECUTE/DEALLOCATE into `IF @sql IS NOT NULL THEN`.